# NSPredicate for multiday events in a given range

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, nspredicate, fetch

I am stuck in one predicate

I need to fetch array of events which comes between in the given period of month.
**If given date is July month .i.e. 1-31st July.. then I need event1, event 2, event 3, event 5, event6**

so I have event startDate and endDate

```
Event 1 - June 10 - July 14
Event 2 - July 4
Event 3 - July 7
Event 4 - June 9
Event 5 - July 1-July 3
Event 6 - May 1 - Dec 10
```

I have tried following but it will only return event2, event3

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ >= %%@ AND %@ < %%@", @"startTime", @"endTime"], startDate, endDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSInteger month = 7; // given month 

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setDay:0];
[components setMonth:month];

NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components1 setDay:31];
[components1 setMonth:month];

NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components1];

NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date =< %@)", startDate, endDate];
NSArray* filteredArray = [yourarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];  // your array
```

Comment: Did you mean [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startTime >= %@) AND (endTime =< %@)", startDate, endDate] ? Not returning exact search results.